# Is is possible to sort xml attribute values alphabetically using python?

Tags: python, xml, sorting

I have a similar xml file, in which I would like to sort the **attribute values** of the a tag in alphabetical order.

```
<x name = something>
  <a name = BBB> </a>
  <a name = AAA> </a>
  <a name = CCC> </a>
</x>
<x name = random>
  <a name = CCC> </a>
  <a name = BBB> </a>
  <a name = AAA> </a>
</x>
```

I want the output xml file to be:

```
<x name = something>
  <a name = AAA> </a>
  <a name = BBB> </a>
  <a name = CCC> </a>
</x>
<x name = random>
  <a name = AAA> </a>
  <a name = BBB> </a>
  <a name = CCC> </a>
</x>
```

Comment: You're sorting _tags_ by the value of a certain attribute, not attribute values. But yes, it is possible.

Comment: @AKX thanks for the clarification,  how should I go about sorting tags by alphabetical order of certain attribute values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this is maybe what you're looking for.

I've embedded an example document in the source, but you can load the XML from disk or wherever you want.

The idea is to have a recursive function that takes an arbitrary condition (predicate) function and a `sort` key function; that way you can choose which trees should get reordered – or if you want to just reorder everything, it can be a function that always returns True.

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree


def sort_tree(node, sort_cond, sort_key):
    # If this node matches the condition,
    if sort_cond(node):
        # ... sort the children and reapply into the node.
        node[:] = sorted(node, key=sort_key)

    # Recurse down the tree.
    for child in node:
        sort_tree(child, sort_cond, sort_key)


tree = etree.XML("""
<document>
    <x name="xxsomething">
      <a name="BBB">some thing bbb</a>
      <a name="AAA">aaa some thing</a>
      <a name="CCC">some ccc thing</a>
    </x>
    <x name="aarandom">
      <a name="ZXY">asdf</a>
      <a name="888">ghkj</a>
      <a name="uuu">tyiu</a>
    </x>
</document>
""")
sort_tree(
    tree,
    sort_cond=lambda node: all(child.tag == "a" for child in node),
    sort_key=lambda node: node.get("name"),
)
print(etree.tostring(tree, encoding='unicode'))
```

Output:

```
<document>
    <x name="xxsomething">
      <a name="AAA">aaa some thing</a>
      <a name="BBB">some thing bbb</a>
      <a name="CCC">some ccc thing</a>
    </x>
    <x name="aarandom">
      <a name="888">ghkj</a>
      <a name="ZXY">asdf</a>
      <a name="uuu">tyiu</a>
    </x>
</document>
```

(Note how the `x` tags weren't reordered even if they're in the wrong "name" order since the `cond` function only applies if all children of the node are `a` nodes.)

Answer (score -1):

For `.xml` file like:

```
<x name='random'>
  <a name='CCC'> </a>
  <a name='BBB'> </a>
  <a name='AAA'> </a>
</x>
```

1. Load data with [`ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html).
2. Collect tag names values.
3. Sort values.
4. Update tag name values.
5. Save updated data to new xml file.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree

# open file
root = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('data.xml')

# collect tag names values
names = []
for element in root.findall('a'):
    value = element.attrib.get('name')
    names.append(value)

# sort values
sorted_names = sorted(names)

# update data
count = 0
for element in root.findall('a'):
    value = element.attrib.get('name')
    element.attrib['name'] = sorted_names[count]
    count +=1

# save new data
root.write('new.xml')
```

**Output:**

```
<x name="random">
  <a name="AAA"> </a>
  <a name="BBB"> </a>
  <a name="CCC"> </a>
</x>
```

Comment: This will do weird things with nested trees of tags.

Comment: @AKX this is example how to get started. For nested tags need to create another loop over `x` tag.

Comment: No, consider a case where a tree has `<x><a/><a/><a/></x><y><a/><a/><a/></y>`. This code would sort all a elements throughout all subtrees (not to mention it doesn't sort elements at all, just shuffles name attributes around).